# Alterar link da imagem dinamicamente dentro do <img src>

Tags: php

Bom dia, amigos, pergunta de iniciante.

Tenho uma consulta que mostra numa tabela todos os registros do meu BD. Porém como são muitas colunas, limitei a exibir os nomes, data de nascimento alguns poucos dados. E criei uma última coluna com o link "dados completos" que ao ser clicado vai mostrar em outra janela todos os dados daquele registro. Esse é o código:

`<a href="dadoscompletos.php?codigo=">Dados Completos`

Assim, a página abre com os dados completos daquele registro.

Meu problema é com a imagem. Quero exibir a foto do que está salva na pasta "img". O nome da imagem é o código do registro. Tentei assim:

```
<?php

include("classe/conecta.php");
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM CadPessoas WHERE Cod='$codigo'";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    
  <body>
           <?php 
           while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
          
          <img src="img/(['$codigo']).jpg">
```

Mas não funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar com essa última linha do meu código? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   include("classe/conecta.php");
   $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
   $consulta = "SELECT * FROM CadPessoas WHERE Cod='$codigo'";
   $con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
   ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php 
         while($dado = $con->fetch_array())
         {
            ?>
            <img src="img/<?=$dado['codigo'];?>.jpg"> //short hand do php
            <?
         }?>
```